# Matching faces in Simplicial Set theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

Let $X$ be a simplicial set. The elements $$x_0,\dots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\dots,x_n\in X_{n-1}$$ are said to be **matching faces** with respect to $i$ if $$d_jx_k=d_kx_{j+1}$$ for $j\geq k$ and $k,j+1\neq i$.

My question is what is the geometric intuition behind the term matching faces? Why the terminology "matching", which suggests "similarity" of some sort?

Thanks for enlightenment!

Comment: They match along lower-dimensional faces. Try drawing a picture for $n = 2$ or $n = 3$.

Comment: @Zhenlin In other words, they are "adjacent" or "touching each other"?

Comment: Yes, adjacent is a good word.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly as if $x_k$ were the $k$th face of some $n$-simplex $y$ (i.e. $x_k = d_k y$), except that the full simplex $y$ may not necessarily exist. As Zhen Lin suggest in the comments, drawing a picture is quite helpful. For example when $n = 2$ and $i = 0$, this looks like this:

[image]

For $n=3$ it looks like a (hollow) tetrahedron with the face opposite to the vertex $i$ removed; the $x_k$ are the remaining faces (with $x_k$ being opposite to the vertex $k$). When the simplex $y$ exists for all combinations of matching faces, the simplicial set is said to be a Kan complex, or fibrant.

Comment: I think your picture in uncorrect. If you set n=2, you should have 3 segments (or 1-simplex) being x_0, x_1 and x_2 (how do you write in LaTeX style?). Thus, the matching space should looks like a triangle, for which we do not necessarily have a 2-simplex (a triangle as an area and not only as three joint segments) filling it. What you describe is more like a Horn.

Comment: @Abel-Henri-GuillaumeMilor Count again. The OP provides $x_0, ..., x_{i-1}, x_{i+1}, ..., x_n$. For $n=2$ and $i=0$, this means providing $x_1, x_2$. Two simplices. Not three. What I describe is, indeed, a horn, or really a map $\Lambda^2_0 \to X$.